# Invoking ImportClass in Java 6

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am working on a project that requires that a Java class be called from a piece of Javascript that was executed by a separate piece of Java code. It did originally work in Java 7.51 but it needs to work in Java 1.6.0_27 as well but fails with a `function importclass must be called with a class` error message.

The two JARs were generated through Eclipse Indigo using the Export > JAR command.

I created a simple MCVE as below to demonstrate the problem. The stack trace from executing with the following command line...

`java -cp Sanity.jar;SanityCheck.jar -jar SanityCheck.jar`

...is the following:

```
    javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Function importClass must be called with a class; had "[JavaPackage com.sanity.Sanity]" instead. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
        at com.sanity.SanityCheck.<init>(SanityCheck.java:22)
        at com.sanity.SanityCheck.main(SanityCheck.java:52)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sanity.SanityCheck.invoke(SanityCheck.java:31)
        at com.sanity.SanityCheck.main(SanityCheck.java:53)
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

Sanity.java (in its own JAR of the same name)

```
    package com.sanity;

    public class Sanity {

        public Sanity() {}

        public void doCheck() {
            System.out.println("Sanity Check Passed!");
        }

    }
```

SanityCheck.java (in its own JAR of the same name)

```
    package com.sanity;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    import javax.script.Invocable;
    import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
    import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
    import javax.script.ScriptException;

    public class SanityCheck {

        private Invocable invoker;

        public SanityCheck(String script) {
            try {
                ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
                ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

                engine.eval(script);
                invoker = (Invocable) engine;
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void invoke() {
            try {
                invoker.invokeFunction("run");
            } catch (ScriptException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Sanity.js")));
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                reader.close();

                SanityCheck check = new SanityCheck(builder.toString());
                check.invoke();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sanity.js

```
    importClass(Packages.com.sanity.Sanity);

    function run() {
            var sanObj = new Sanity();
            sanObj.doCheck();
    }
```

Comment: What is the output of `java -version`?

Comment: `java version "1.6.0_27"`

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: alright, got it. See updated answer.

Comment: @DavidP.Caldwell Hmm... still fails with the same error on my machine when I use the `java -cp Sanity.jar;SanityCheck.jar com.sanity.SanityCheck`. I am going to accept your answer on the grounds that it does work for someone (proving the point about ImportClass). It has to be something on my machine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was down to the JAR file that was being called from the Javascript was compiled against Java 7, not Java 6. A quick test trying to run a main method in Eclipse soon revealed this.

A quick recompilation of the JAR file and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have good news: the problem has nothing to do with your Java or JavaScript code. It has to do with the effect of the command:

```
java -cp [...] -jar <jar-file>
```

When executing that command, the `-cp` argument is ignored, and the `<jar-file>` is used as the *entire* classpath.

From the [Java 6 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) for the `-jar` option to the `java` tool:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

So a version of your command that would work is:

```
java -cp Sanity.jar;SanityCheck.jar com.sanity.SanityCheck
```

I reproduced your example with the following directory structure, without modifying your code:

```
Sanity.js
com/
    sanity/
        Sanity.java
        SanityCheck.java
```

... and then ran the following command from the top-level directory:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac com/sanity/*.java && /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -classpath . com.sanity.SanityCheck
```

... and got

```
Sanity Check Passed!
```

Comment: So I guess original question should be closed, since it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @eis Not quite - The question (and this is may bad here) refers to 2 JARs, not one. Least it proves the concept works.